# Trouble with enterpreting Faraday's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

$$ \nabla \times \textbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t} $$

My interpretation of this equation is that:

- A steady magnetic field will result in an electric field that is $0$.
- A varying magnetic field will result in a varying electric field.

How can I produce a steady and non zero electric field then?

Comment: To clarify, you want to know how to create a steady electric field using magnetic fields and *no charges*?

Comment: @Philip I am not entrely sure here. I am thinking of the experiments that showed that steady current produced a steady B-field. Then Faraday showed that to induce a current you need a changing magnetic field. Since current density and E-field are related by conductivity I was thinking how can one induce a steady E-field in such a way that it then leads to a steady current (DC current).

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think that a steady electric field can really induce a steady current. A steady electric field implies that the charges are *accelerated* (since they have a force of $q\mathbf{E}$ acting on them). Accelerated charges don't constitute a "steady" current. Also, keep in mind the order of things: a changing magnetic field induces an electric field **in such a way as to oppose the change in the magnetic field**. The current this electric field produces need not (and, as far as I can see, *cannot*) be steady if it has to cancel out a the effect of a changing $\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: But the thing is that the drift velocity of an electron is steady due to collisions and hence the acceleration is zero after a while. So I am thinking the current must then be steady.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, your interpretation is not 100% right.

The equation you quote (Maxwell-Faraday) is:
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

Then, is $\bf{B}$ is steady (particularly in time as it's what is interesting in that case) then the field $\bf{E}$ will have a **curl** equal to $0$. But $\nabla\times\bf{E}$ does not imply $\mathbf{E}=0$. It only implies that $\mathbf{E}$ is steady (but, that's true, the case $\bf{E}=0$ is included in the possibilities but is not mandatory).

So, a constant and steady magnetic field can be used to create a constant and steady electic field.

Comment: I initially wrote this and then deleted my answer since I couldn't come up with a steady magnetic field that did indeed induce a steady electric field. Do you have one in mind? Because as far as I can see, one *needs* a time-varying magnetic field to induce an electric field.

Comment: You’re quite right, as an electric field can not be induced by both a steady and time-independent magnetic field. But a steady electric field can be induced by a not-steady but time-independent magnetic field (Maxwell-Ampere). And that’s what I understood to be the question: we want a steady electric field induced by a magnetic field. But I might have misunderstood and in that case you’re right, a time-and-space independent magnetic field wouldn’t induce an electric field.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "a steady electric field can be induced by a not-steady but time-independent magnetic field (Maxwell-Ampere)" and "time-and-space independent magnetic field wouldn’t induce an electric field" in basic terms?

Comment: Sure, it's basically the 4th Maxwell Law (Maxwell-Ampere) that states $$\nabla\times\mathbf{B} = \mu_0\mathbf{j}+\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$ So a space-varying magnetic field can induce a time-varying electric field, that can be steady (in space).